# How get all values from all inputs?

Tags: jquery

I have Inputs

```
<input name="v[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="v[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input name="v[]" value="3" type="checkbox">
<input name="v[]" value="4" type="checkbox">
```

Where checked with this code

```
$(document).on('click',"tbody tr", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('info')) {
        $(this).removeClass('info');
        $(this).find('input[name="v[]"]').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('info');
        $(this).find('input[name="v[]"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

I want get array of checked Inputs with their values. How i can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var values = $.map($('input[name="v[]"]:checked'), function(el,i) { return el.value });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3Kxb/4/)

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'get'` in a jsFiddle using jQuery 1.8.3 or 1.9.1

Comment: Now it work, but this code getting ALL values from ALL inputs, while i want get ALL values from ALL inputs WHERE checked.

Comment: Was'nt paying attention to this, but @SheikhHeera fixed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.serializeArray` should do it

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    console.log($('input').serializeArray());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbm4T/

Example of just getting inputs of type `checkbox`
http://jsfiddle.net/cbm4T/1/

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    console.log($('input[type=checkbox]').serializeArray());
});
```

Comment: What if there are other inputs on the form ?

Comment: You would just need to update the selector to be more specific. I've added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = $.map($('input[name="v[]"]:checked'), function(obj) {
              return $(obj).val();

});
```

edited: others beat me to it.

**AND**

if for some reason you wanted the reverse. checkboxes that are not clicked and their values.

```
var values = $.map($('input[name="v[]"]:not(:checked)'), function(obj) {
              return $(obj).val();

});
```